# LED Mini Bulb Project wiring issue

Tags: low-power

OK, working on a project that would require the use of only one LED or mini bulb from a Christmas tree string of lights. I understand I can't use them direct from 110 volt or it will blow a circuit or ruin bulb. Can I put a resistor inline with the wiring to make it work and if so what kind or size. I need to use 110 volts input. Do not want to use a transformer for size and space reasons.Also is there something else I can use for this purpose, just need it to glow. Thanks

UPDATE: Ok I am using a suggestion form one of you all and decided to go the Neon Bulb route, but now would like something a little bit brighter, are some neons brighter than others? I tried the neons and not quite bright enough. Thanks

Comment: What current do you need through the LED and what is the frequency of the 110 volt supply? Given those values, someone will be able to show you a circuit which uses just a fuse, a capacitor, and a diode in addition to your LED.

Comment: In re update: how bright do you want it? What colour? Is this for illumination or just an indicator light?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Very simple circuit. Use a series resistor before the + output to lower V down for the LED.

Comment: As simple as this circuit may be, it needs a **"WARNING: THIS CIRCUIT CAN KILL YOU. ALWAYS EXERCISE CAUTION WHEN DEALING WITH LINE VOLTAGES."**.

Comment: @m.alin  Sure can kill you. I don't eat Silica Gel or dry my hair in the shower either. So ALL circuits using AC need this warning, or should there be a base assumption that there is a modicum of intelligence of the users here? I'm serious...